# Why texts are not changing in activity?

Tags: android, kotlin

By studying `databinding`, I created a simple activity to start exercising.
And have the following codes:

**MainActivity:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val users = UserProfile("First Name","Last Name","Off",false)
    val handlerbtn = HandlerButtonClick()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding: ActivityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main)
        binding.user = users
        binding.handler = handlerbtn

    }
}
```

**Class for click:**

```
class HandlerButtonClick {
    fun onClickButton(view: View, user: UserProfile) {
        var msg = ""
        if(!user.isOnline){
            msg = "Online"
            user.firstName = "Henrique"
            user.lastName = "Mendes"
            user.status = "Online"
            user.isOnline = true

        }else{
            msg = "Offline"
            user.firstName = "First Name"
            user.lastName = "Last Name"
            user.status = "Offline"
            user.isOnline = false
        }

        Toast.makeText(view.context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

**UserProfile Class:**

```
class UserProfile {
    var firstName: String = ""
    var lastName: String = ""
    var status: String = ""
    var isOnline: Boolean = false

    constructor(firstNames: String, lastNames: String, statuss: String, isOnlines: Boolean) {
        this.firstName = firstNames
        this.lastName = lastNames
        this.status = statuss
        this.isOnline = isOnlines
    }
}
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="user"
            type="com.dev.bob.testdatabinding2.UserProfile" />
        <variable
            name="handler"
            type="com.dev.bob.testdatabinding2.HandlerButtonClick" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.dev.bob.testdatabinding2.MainActivity">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1.0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@{user.isOnline?@color/colorGreen : @color/colorAccent}" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="@{user.firstName}" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="@{user.lastName}" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="@{user.status}" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{(view)-> handler.onClickButton(view, user)}"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

The toast works fine, that is, the variable `msg` changes. But my texts on the screen do not change. What should I do to make them change according to what is placed in each condition (`If` / `else`)?

What I say is, by clicking the button, `firstName` does not change to Henry or First Name (again)

Comment: Did you try debugging to check `user` value to make sure it match `users` variable in MainActivity?

Comment: The variable is the same, since it is the one that is explicit in XML. But how could I know? Values are changed in the Handler class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It behave the right way. From the [document](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#data_objects):

> Any plain old Java object (POJO) may be used for data binding, but
>   modifying a POJO will not cause the UI to update. The real power of
>   data binding can be used by giving your data objects the ability to
>   notify when data changes. There are three different data change notification mechanisms, Observable objects, observable fields, and observable collections.

Or you can try two-way data binding using [this](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/two-way-data-binding-on-android-observing-your-view-with-xml/) quick and dirty approach:

Your  tag `android:text` is missing a `=`, after the `@:`. It should be `android:text="@={user.firstName}"`. The `@={}` means "two way data binding". The `@{}` is one way data binding.

Ex:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:text="@={user.firstName}" />
```

Comment: I changed it as you mentioned, but it did not work, there's something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @HenriqueMendes I forgot to give the full approach: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/two-way-data-binding-on-android-observing-your-view-with-xml/.

Comment: I just show you that you think your POJO can "auto update" value for you, but it's not, that answered your question, right? Btw you should follow one in three standard approach which recommended by Google in the document.

Comment: I read the document. My observable class has to be UserProfile, is that correct?

Comment: @HenriqueMendes Yes! Your UserProfile model class is called POJO (in Java).

Answer (score 0):

You can't just assign new value to variable and observe changes on UI. You should notify "DataBinding" somehow. There are few ways to do it.

First one is to make UserProfile extend `BaseObservable` and notify when some property is changed:

```
class UserProfile : BaseObservable {

    @get:Bindable
    var firstName: String = ""
        set(value) {
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.firstName)
        }

    @get:Bindable
    var lastName: String = ""
        set(value) {
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.lastName)
        }

    ... do same for other fields ...

    constructor(firstNames: String, lastNames: String, statuss: String, isOnlines: Boolean) {

        this.firstName = firstNames
        this.lastName = lastNames
        this.status = statuss
        this.isOnline = isOnlines
    }
}
```

Second one is assigning new `UserProfile` to `ActivityMainBinding` after changes:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val users = UserProfile("First Name","Last Name","Off",false)
    lateinit var handlerbtn: HandlerButtonClick

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding: ActivityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main)
        binding.user = users
        handlerbtn = HandlerButtonClick(binding)
        binding.handler = handlerbtn
    }
}
```

Then you should change `HandlerButtonClick` class:

```
class HandlerButtonClick(val binding: ActivityMainBinding) {
    fun onClickButton(view: View, user: UserProfile) {
        var msg = ""
        if(!user.isOnline){
            //changes
        }else{
            //changes   
        }
        binding.users = user
        Toast.makeText(view.context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```